Components of Killing vectors being zero
The following is a question from a GR worksheet given by my professor:


Does the following line element:
$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + e^{\alpha t}(dr^2+r^2\vartheta^2+r^2\sin^2\vartheta d\varphi^2), \qquad [\alpha=\mathrm{constant}], $$
admit a time-like Killing vector? If yes, then determine the condition for the same. If not, prove explicitly.


I solved it using the Killing equation which is $$\nabla_\alpha\xi_\beta+\nabla_\beta\xi_\alpha=0$$where $\nabla_\alpha$ represents the usual covariant derivative in GR. Having the following values for the metric, $$g_{tt}=-1,\:\:g_{rr}=e^{\alpha t},\:\:g_{\vartheta\vartheta}=e^{\alpha t}r^2,\:\:g_{\varphi\varphi}=e^{\alpha t}r^2\sin^2(\vartheta)$$ and the Lie-derivative of the metric tensor becoming zero gives $$\cal L_\xi g_{\mu \nu}=\xi^\alpha g_{\mu \nu,\alpha}+\xi^\alpha_{\ \ \ ,\mu}g_{\nu\alpha} + \xi^\alpha_{\ \ \ ,\nu}g_{\mu\alpha}=0$$ Using the Killing equation, I get by myself, the following governing equations for the components of the killing vector: $$\xi_{\vartheta,\vartheta}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\vartheta\vartheta}\xi_\lambda=\Gamma^t_{\vartheta\vartheta}\xi_t+\Gamma^r_{\vartheta\vartheta}\xi_r$$ $$\xi_{\varphi,\varphi}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\varphi\varphi}\xi_\lambda=\Gamma^t_{\varphi\varphi}\xi_t+\Gamma^r_{\varphi\varphi}\xi_r+\Gamma^\vartheta_{\varphi\varphi}\xi_\vartheta$$ The other Christoffel symbols being zero. Clearly, this equation involves the $\vartheta-$component of the killing vector $\xi_\alpha$, but when the professor did the solution roughly, he told the class that the $\vartheta-$ and $\varphi-$ component of the killing vector will be zero (argument - the metric is spherically symmetric and isotropic metric), and calculated the norm using the $r$ and $t$ components only as $$\xi^\alpha\xi_\alpha = g_{tt}(\xi^t)^2+g_{rr}(\xi^r)^2$$ I have a little confusion here, as for a spherical symmetry in a metric of spacetime, the killing vector should have non zero components in the $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ direction, because, in those directions, the metric is form invariant as we can see. So, how do we apriori know that those components will be zero in this case? Is it because we are told to check the time-like property of the killing vector? I am a little confused, please help me. An explanation of this would be helpful.

The $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ components of killing vectors being zero could mean that the $\xi^t$ or $\xi^r$ may not have any angular components. Are you sure your prof said there is no angular Killing vector fields? bcs that is clearly not true

@KP99 So, does that mean that, as moving in the temporal and radial direction will not depend on the angular coordinates $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$, we can choose a Killing vector such that its angular components are zero and calculate the norm with that?
